# What do angle brackets mean as a part of the return type? <T> T

Tags: java, generics

For this method what does the `<T>` part mean as a part of the return type for this method? Is it where I would specify a `.class` file? Is it even part of the return type definition? What purpose does it serve? Is it defining the class type to be used by the second argument `Class<T> requiredType` or is it not for argument definition?

```
public <T> T queryForObject(String sql, Class<T> requiredType, Map<String, ?> args) throws DataAccessException {
    return getNamedParameterJdbcOperations().queryForObject(sql, args, requiredType);
}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals I disagree. The conext of the question is what <T> means in relation to the second T. What is the relationship between <T> and T?

Comment: Not a good choice of 'duplicate question' at all.

Comment: @KentJohnson but still its a duplicate, this question has been asked here many times :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public <T> T queryForObject(String sql, Class<T> requiredType, Map<String, ?> args) throws DataAccessException {
```

1. `<T>` ---> is not a return type  you are declaring generic type at method level, so that you can use this type `T` inside your method.
2. T   ----> is a return type of your method

Comment: So, let me get this right, as a part of the method signature you can declare a new generic type that can be used not only as the return type but can be taken as that method's parameter? Or, is the `Class<T>` parameter declaring a new generic type in addition to the generic type declared earlier in the method signature? Thanks for the answer, PermGenError!

Comment: The `<T>` after `public` is declaring the type parameter. `Class<T>` is just using this parameter that was declared earlier. The parameter is a way of saying whatever class is passed in as `requiredType`, the return type of the method will be the same type as that.

Comment: How is that line of code (in OPs post) used when implemented? Is it something like this...? `instanceOfT.queryForObject();` Which the returns another object of type T?

Answer (score 1):

`<T>` is just defining a generic type `T` which can then be referred to in your method signature. Without it your code won't compile.